# adb backup disabled on phone

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, adb, windows

I am attempting to run an adb backup to my computer from my Samsung Galaxy Nexus, version maguro, v4.2.2 (I guess it's worth mentioning I'm running Windows 7 on my computer). I have tried this with two methods, using the WugFresh Nexus Toolkit, and directly from the command line using the adb executable I got from the android sdk. Each time I attempt it, the adb backup page comes up fine on my phone, but the button to accept the backup is not clickable. I can deny the backup fine, but not accept it. Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

The drivers are the most likely problem, but I am running the signed Samsung drivers that I successfully installed from the Nexus Toolkit. Could anyone additionally corroborate if they are/have been a problem? I would consider uninstalling them in favor of another possibility, but don't know which alternative is best, or how to remove the damned signed drivers from my computer so they stop auto-installing.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: It might very well be that ADB Backup in your device is borked: I have two devices here were exactly that is the case (though with other symptoms: I can hit the button, but get zero bytes). To verify, you might want to try with [Helium - App Sync and Backup](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.koushikdutta.backup) -- which utilizes `adb backup` for backup/restore (you could call it a "graphical frontend to adb backup/restore"). If that fails as well, it's rather not your driver (which I doubt anyway).

Answer (score 0):

1. try a usb2 (instead of usb3) port: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2077799#6
2. do you have a sony? http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1696320
3. check your command: http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1851811#5